# PIL ImageDraw.textsize returns incorrect height

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm having an issue with PIL's ImageDraw module, specifically the `Draw.textsize` method. This method is supposed to take a string and a font, and return the width and height that the string would occupy when rendered in that font. It seems to have a lower bound on the height that it returns, though: I can't convince it to return anything lower than `43`. Here's an example ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nndzX.png)) to show what I'm looking at (bounding boxes drawn around the text based on the returned width & height), and here's the code that produced it:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont # PIL 1.1.7; Python 2.6.6

im = Image.open(r'C:\test\blank.png').convert('RGB')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

TEXTCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
X = 10
Y = 3

for fontsize in xrange(8, 51):
    # Other fonts behave the same way
    font = ImageFont.truetype('Arial.ttf', fontsize)

    text = 'Hello, World! Size %d' % fontsize

    width, height = draw.textsize(text, font=font)
    print 'Font size %d: %d x %d' % (fontsize, width, height)

    bbox = [(X, Y), (X+width, Y+height)]
    draw.rectangle(bbox, outline=TEXTCOLOR)
    draw.text((X, Y), text, font=font, fill=TEXTCOLOR)
    Y += height + 3

im.show()
```

Once the font gets up to about size 38, the bounding box stretches to match it correctly, but before that, it's set to a static `43`. The question is, does anyone know why ImageDraw is behaving this way, and does anyone know of a way to fix it? I'm currently working around the issue by setting:

```
width = min(width, fontsize+1)
```

...but that's obviously not the most robust solution ever devised.

Comment: Where did you get the PIL module you're using? When I try to run your code under Python 2.7.3 I get an `ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed` error.

Comment: @martineau I'm not sure where I got it originally (I do remember it being a pain in the neck to set up, though). The installer I used is named `PIL-fork-1.1.7.win32-py2.6.exe`, but no luck finding that online now.

Comment: The `ImportError` I'm encountering is a common problem, which I'm trying to resolve. When/if I do, I'll take another look at your problem.

Comment: you could give pillow a try

Comment: @martineau Thanks; I remember writing down how I solved that same problem, but not I don't know where I put my notes...

Comment: @tovmeod I intend to move on to Pillow when I can, but at this moment I have an extremely short timeframe to get this working (as well as possible), so I'd prefer to stick with the library that's already (mostly) working (for me).

Comment: @tovmeod For the record, I ran this test on another machine with Python 2.7.3 and Pillow 2.0.0 and the problem was gone--looks like that may be the way to go.

Comment: I'll second the motion to use Pillow 2.0.0. I gave up trying to fix the `ImportError` with PIL 1.1.7 for Python 2.7.4 and did an `easy_install` of the `Pillow-2.0.0-py2.7-win32.egg` file from the downloads section of the [Pillow 2.0.0 Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0#downloads) and your program starts working fine as you can see from [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/PIL_textsize_problem.png) image file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue seems to be that PIL is super buggy and essentially no longer supported. The problem mentioned here isn't the worst of it (e.g. no one is able to replicate it because it's so hard to even install...).

In light of all the troubles that seem to be rampant in PIL 1.1.7, the best solution seems to be to simply install [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0#downloads) and move along. It doesn't require code changes for code that already runs PIL (it's a PIL fork so it installs the "PIL" library), and it seems to be vastly friendlier (and still active). As the commenters on the question have confirmed, it's a simple, trouble-free install and it actually works like it's supposed to.